# Drivers other than pdftex.def not supported, epstopdf problem?

Tags: packages, pdf, epstopdf

I get this error when using Quick Build (pdfLatex + view pdf)

> File
>   /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
>
> Type
>   Warning
>
> Line
>   line 1
>
> Message
>   Drivers other than `pdftex.def' are not supported

I'm pretty sure this is the section of the log that refers to the error.

> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
>   Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
>   Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
>   (etexcmds) That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
>   (etexcmds) that some package has redefined \expanded.
>   (etexcmds) In the latter case, load this package earlier.
>   )))
>   Package epstopdf Warning: Drivers other than `pdftex.def' are not supported.

(The last line is in blue)

The first few lines of my document are:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage[authoryear,sectionbib,round]{natbib}  
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{sidecap}  
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{placeins}  
\usepackage{subfigure}
```

Comment: By the way I'm running this through Texmaker, strangely when I run the .tex file through TexWorks this error doesn't appear and the .pdf is created just fine.

Comment: texworks and texmaker are simply editors, neither actually processes the file or generates errors. Presumably in one case you are using latex instead of pdflatex.

Comment: Yes true, was using PDFLatex in both though.. it has actually randomly started working on both without that error - strange!!

Comment: latex doesn't act randomly, it just follows instructions (even when they're wrong:-) do you want to close the question (or delete) seems it can't have a real answer now

Comment: Yep will close!